# Are EJB implemented with sockets?

Tags: java, sockets, ejb

Does EJB internally use sockets while exchanging beans with clients?

Comment: I'm curious on the question behind the question.  All client-server communication in Java uses Sockets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know EJB is implemented RMI and RMI is implemented by using Sockets

Comment: Do you have any example how RMI internally handles Socket programming

Comment: It's not specified. The only examples are in the source code.

Comment: Minor trivia: many servers don't actually use the RMI protocol (WebLogic, WebSphere, OpenEJB).  The actual spec requirement is that application developers ensure their objects are RMI-compatible.  The server is actually free to use whatever protocol it wants.